# TypeError: this._input is undefined in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I have added a simple Handlebar to get the content from the JSON data, but iam getting this error - "TypeError: this._input is undefined" in console. iam getting the correct output, but still i get these errors always..

```
<div class="profileSectionhandle">
     <script id="profileTabs" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
             {{#profilecontent}}
             .......
             {{/profilecontent}}
          </script>
     </div>

var source = $("#profileTabs").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$(".profileSectionhandle").html(template(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to `console.log(source)`, then it will return undefined.  This means that `$("#profileTabs").html()` isn't in the DOM my the time your code runs, and then you are trying to compile `undefined`.

Chances are that your page is not loaded by the time your js calls on your handlebars.  Either place your function in `$(document).ready(function () {...})` if you are working on a web app (with jquery), or `$( document ).bind( "pagebeforeshow", function() {...})` for a mobile app (with jquery mobile).